# Error in Table View Controller When using a segue Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift

I've ran into a problem and i cant resolve it

TableViewController:

```
var items: [String?] = ["door","table","chair"]
var givenDescription: [String?] = ["Change the description using 

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UIToolbarDelegate {
the edit option"]
@IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!



override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myTableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return items.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = givenDescription[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class AddViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var newPic: Bool?

//Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var addName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var addDescription: UITextField!
@IBAction func addImage(_ sender: Any) {
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Select Image From", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: nil)
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.newPic = true
    }
    let cameraRoll = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera Roll", style: .default, handler: nil)
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.newPic = false
    }
    myAlert.addAction(cameraAction)
    myAlert.addAction(cameraRoll)
    self.present(myAlert, animated: true)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
    if mediaType.isEqual(to: kUTTypeImage as String) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imageView.image = image

        if newPic == true {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(imageError), nil)
        }
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func imageError(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSErrorPointer, contextInfo:UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if error != nil {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Save Failed", message: "Failed to save image", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//Action
@IBAction func create(_ sender: Any) {
    if (addName.text != "") {
        items.append(addName.text!)
        addName.text = ""
    }
    if (addDescription.text != "") {
        givenDescription.append(addDescription.text!)
        addDescription.text = ""
    }
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}   
}
```

Comment: Your `items` array contains multiple elements but your `givenDescription` array contains only one element. Unless you keep them perfectly in synch size wise you cannot use `indexPath.row` when accessing `givenDescription`. _Edit:_ looking at the other class it is clearly the function `create` that needs to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can "fix" the `create` function in several ways, for example like this:

```
@IBAction func create(_ sender: Any) {
    if (addName.text != "" && addDescription.text != "") {
        items.append(addName.text!)
        addName.text = ""
        givenDescription.append(addDescription.text!)
        addDescription.text = ""
    }
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

but a much better option is to create a simple struct

```
struct Item {
    var name: String
    var itemDescription: String
}
```

and use it instead

```
@IBAction func create(_ sender: Any) {
    if (addName.text != "" && addDescription.text != "") { //or just check one depending on if one is more important
        let item = Item(name: addName.text!, itemDescription: addDescription.text!)
        items.append(item)
    }
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

and the `items` array is defined as

```
var items: [Item]()
```

andd for your table view

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.itemDescription

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I am still getting an error Index out of range in the TableViewController on line 51

Comment: on the code " vc?.rcDescription = givenDescription[indexPath.row]"

Comment: @Vlad you should not be using `givenDescription` if you implemented my recommended solution using a struct.

Comment: no, I didn't use a struct I used this one @IBAction func create(_ sender: Any) {
    if (addName.text != "" && addDescription.text != "") {
        items.append(addName.text!)
        addName.text = ""
        givenDescription.append(addDescription.text!)
        addDescription.text = ""
    }
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

Comment: @Vlad Do you have any other place in your code where you add, remove or clear any of the two arrays? You need to keep them in synch all the time. Line 51 doesn't seem to be part of your posted code but I am not sure it is important to see it.

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer so simple.

```
@IBAction func create(_ sender: Any) {
if (addName.text != "" && addDescription.text != "") {
    items.append(addName.text!)
    addName.text = ""
    givenDescription.append(addDescription.text!)
    addDescription.text = ""
}
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

}